# can't exit from nano "File editting" on mac terminal

Tags: macos

can't exit from nano "File editting" on mac terminal
im trying to edit a file in mac os terminal . Once i press Control + O . it just write "o" without any action .

Any one may help  me ? 
thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Control + O` is the shortcut for "WriteOut", which saves modifications, but does not exit the file. To exit nano you need to press `Control + X` (short for "eXit") Which will exit nano, after prompting whether you want to save any changes to the file. You can also press `Control + G` to view the help file with the list of commands.

I assume you already know this, but in case you don't, when I say `Control + X` (for example) it means press the `control` key and the `X` key, but do **not** press the `+` key

Also if (as you say) when you press `Control + O` it just writes the text "o" to screen, your keyboard may have a damaged Control Key, or you may have remapped your control key to do something else in software. You can try a different keyboard, and make sure you don't have any keyboard remapping software active.

Comment: does not work. Ctrl + O opens up save as file and Ctrl + X does nothing.

Comment: @Prime, are you perhaps trying to use both commands one after the other? After starting the process of saving the file, it'll prompt you to pick the name, etc, which you'll need to finish before using control x. If control X really does nothing when in the main editing interface, I'd suspect that maybe you're running on a weird system that is intercepting the control x before it gets to nano. Or your X key is broken. Or some other weird noncompliant fork of nano, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure out how to exit out of `nano` file editing on Mac command line so I'd like to share some details:

`Control` + `X` would be the right keys to exit out of the `nano` file editing. It will ask you whether you want to save the changes you have made after you hit `Control` + `X`. You can choose `Y` to save, `N` not to save and `Control` + `C` to cancel.

Then it will prompt you to enter `File name to write`, if you don't want to change the file name, you can hit `return`/`enter` on the keyboard. If you want to use another file name, type the new file name in and hit `return`/`enter`. Then you will exit out of the `nano` file editing mode.

`Control` + `O` saves the changes but does not exit.

Answer (score 0):

- Save - `Ctrl + O` then `ENTER`
- Exit - `Ctrl + X`

Thats's it