# Exit nano in terminal. cmd+X is not working

Tags: unix, nano

My OS is macOS Catalina.

I open nano version 2.0.6 in the terminal to edit a file. `nano first-loop.sh`

To exit nano, I have tried Cmd+X and Cmd+SHIFT+X, but none of these two options performs any action.

It is only when I type SHIFT+Esc+X that it reacts. However, most of the times, pressing this would only enable and disable the Help mode. Scarce times when I press this same combination SHIFT+Esc+X is when it asks to save the file: `Save modified buffer (ANSWERING "No" WILL DESTROY CHANGES) ?`

I wonder why the same command can activate two different actions on this stochastic manner (I have not been able to identify a pattern). I find it absurd that I have to press the same key over and over until it decides to react in the way I expect.

Is there any keyboard combination I can use to be certain I will exit nano?

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't exit from nano "File editting" on mac terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886347/cant-exit-from-nano-file-editting-on-mac-terminal)

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a genuine problem. I see the same. CTRL+x does nothing apart from type an x

My fix was it's keyboard related, use the laptop keyb directly and works as expected

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me to exit nano was ctrl+shift+X

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the control key on the left hand side of the keyboard instead of the one on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the proper key to exit nano (*all the times*). The solution:

ctrl+X

I am sorry because this question has been a bit stupid. In case it helps any other user, all the signs ^ in the Help codes mean the key ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was able to close the window by first tapping the `tab` button followed by `control-x`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the escape key instead of ctrl